# Score function - QDA

Tags: probability, probability-theory, machine-learning

I am trying to classify an input feature using QDA.
I have x = [0.5,0.5] I need to find to which class this might belong to. So I decided to use the QDA scoring function `δk(x)=logπ − 1/2log|Σ| − 1/2(x−μ)^TΣ^−1(x−μ)`
I expected this equation to give a single scalar score. However after solving or from the equation it can be seen that the result is a matrix. (in the equation first & second term are scalar whereas third term is a matrix) So how should I decide. Am I understanding some thing wrong ? Kindly help. I googled a lot but what I find is just the formula or solved using any programming language. No worked out example.

Comment: But your third term is a row vector times a matrix times a column vector, which comes out as a scalar, after all.

Comment: @kimchilover so ya I agree.. (x−μ)^T is a column vector, Σ^−1 this is a matrix , (x−μ) is a row vector..is abc = cba ? then your statement will be true

Comment: According to you, $(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)$ is a column times a matrix times a row, which does not make sense as a matrix product.  The true resolution is that $x$ plays the role of a column vector in the equations you are citing, in spite of your programming idiom x=[.5,.5]] which misleads you into thinking it's a row vector.

Comment: @kimchilover Thank you